# Simple XML comparison

Tags: c#, xml

I have a question regarding to a simple comparison between the innerxml of a node. I have write the following simple example, but this is not working by **Innerxml**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;


namespace CompareXML
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = @"<Deals>
             <Deal id='20504'> 
             <Marketarea>H</Marketarea>
             <price>22</price>
             </Deal>
             <Deal id='20505'> 
             <Marketarea>K</Marketarea>
             <price>22</price>
             </Deal>  
            </Deals>";
        string s2 = @"<Deals>
             <Deal id='20504'> 
             <Marketarea>S</Marketarea>
             <price></price>
             </Deal>  
            </Deals>";
        XmlDocument d1 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument d2 = new XmlDocument();
        d1.LoadXml(s1);
        d2.LoadXml(s2);

        int id = 20504;
        var text1 = d1.SelectSingleNode("Deal[@id='"+id+"']").InnerXml;
        var text2 = d2.SelectSingleNode("Deal[@id='" + id + "']").InnerXml;
        if (text1 == text2)
            Console.WriteLine("match");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No match");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

   }
}
```

I cannot understand why when i have a node with attribute the Innerxml doesn't work and when i have just a simple node without attribute for example the node `<Deal>` works.

Thanks in advance!

**ERROR**

[image]

**EDIT**

So i would like from this example to take in the var text the following

```
     <Marketarea>H</Marketarea>
     <price>22</price>
```

and then to compare.

Comment: Do you receive any errors? not working by `Innerxml` means what?

Comment: Yes. I try to upload a screenshot. Gives Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is because [`SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns null - it does this when *no node was found*.

The XPath supplied to SelectSingleNode is wrong, relative to the document. Compare with the following XPath query, which "works" here:

```
d1.SelectSingleNode("/Deals/Deal[@id='"+id+"']").InnerXml;
```

Alternatively:

```
d1.SelectSingleNode("//Deal[@id='"+id+"']").InnerXml;
```

Comment: Ha....funny! Yes it's working now. I will i have a closer look to the function SelectSingleNode. Thanks